# Can we send the JSON obtained from an API as a child component, instead of each individual attribute of the object?

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-component, react-state

I have been trying to send the data obtained by an API call to a child component via state and it doesn't seem to work.

I have been sending each individual attribute of the object as a prop to the child component.

Is there a way to send the whole JSON response as a prop to a child component?

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {},
      name: ""
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.getWeather();
  }
  getWeather(city) {
    fetch(
      `https://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=2da827a3ce074ddb85417374xxxxxx&q=paris`
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.getData(data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return Promise.reject();
      });
  }
  getData(data) {
    var location = data.location.name;

    this.setState({ data: data, name: location });
    console.log(this.state.name);
    console.log(this.state.data);
  }
  render() {
    return <Child name={this.state.name} data={this.state.data} />;
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var data = this.props.data;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
        <h1> {data.current.cloud}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I expect the data object to also be passed to the child but it doesn't and I get a crash screen stating that the data object is undefined.

Is there a way to send the whole JSON obtained in an API call as a prop to a child component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Child` component will render before the `getWeather` api return the data. So `this.props.data` in `Child` component will be `{}`, app crash when you access `data.current.cloud`.

You need to check whether `data` is not empty and it has `current` property. So your code should be

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var data = this.props.data;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
        <h1>{data && data.current ? data.current.cloud : ''}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is always a best practice to do all API calls in method "**ComponentDidMount**" rather than "ComponentWillMount". This will do away with your checking that whether response came from API or not. Once the response comes, component will be re-rendered. So, you can do like below

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.getWeather();
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to @tien Duoung's comment,

You may want to add an extra state variable. You could call it `fetching` or `loading`. The purpose will be to at least display something while your api result is not ready. It could be like so:

this.state = {
      data: {},
      name: "",
      fetching: true
}

In the `.then` of your `getData` method, once data.current is available, `this.setState({ fetching: false })`

getData(data) {
    var location = data.location.name;

```
this.setState({ data: data, name: location, fetching: false });
console.log(this.state.name);
console.log(this.state.data);
```

}

Then pass fetching as a prop to the child component too, and when fetching is true, render a loader component or say a placeholder `<h1>Loading...</h1>`